# Kotlin : How to click on item in a Recyclerview Inside another Recyclerview

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

After seen all the similiar questions, I don't find a solution of my problem, which the description as follows:
In my android app, I use Kotlin as language. In my app, I have a lot of category and each category have a list of products. In my home activity, I create a vertical RecyclerView named "productListOfCategory". In the "productListOfCategory" adapter,a textView to display a category name and a recyclerView to display all related product list. The following code is the description of "ProductListOfProductTypeAdapter" adapter : (ProductType = category)

```
 class ProductListOfProductTypeAdapter(private val context: Context, private val ProductTypeIDWithProduct: Map<String, Array<ProductData>>, private val productTypeDetail: Array<ProductTypeData>)
    : RecyclerView.Adapter<ProductListOfProductTypeAdapter.ViewHolder>(),ProductOfProductTypeAdapter.OnItemClickListener{
    override fun onItemClick(view: View, viewModel: ProductData) {
        val intent = Intent(context,ProductDetail::class.java)
        context.startActivity(intent)
    }
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.item_list_product_product_type, parent, false)
        return ViewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun getItemCount() = ProductTypeIDWithProduct.size

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val itemType = ProductTypeIDWithProduct.keys.elementAt(position)
        holder.productTypeName.text = getName(itemType)

        val arrayProductOfProductType = ProductTypeIDWithProduct[itemType] as ArrayList<ProductData>

        holder.productListOfProductType.apply {
            holder.productListOfProductType.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context, RecyclerView.HORIZONTAL, false)
            holder.productListOfProductType.adapter = ProductOfProductTypeAdapter(arrayProductOfProductType,context,this@ProductListOfProductTypeAdapter)
        }

    }

    inner class ViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        val productTypeName: TextView = itemView.textViewProductTypeName
        val productListOfProductType: RecyclerView = itemView.recyclerViewProductOfProductType
    }
```

"ProductOfProductTypeAdapter" is the second adapter which the code as the following :

```
class ProductOfProductTypeAdapter(private val products: ArrayList<ProductData>, private val context: Context,private val mListener: OnItemClickListener)
    : RecyclerView.Adapter<ProductOfProductTypeAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.item_product_featured, parent, false)
        return ViewHolder(view)

    }

    override fun getItemCount() = products.size

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val productItem = products[position] as Map<String, Map<String, String>>

        holder.productName.text = productItem["name"]?.get("En").toString()
        holder.productWeight.text = productItem["weight"].toString().plus(context.resources.getString(R.string.ml))
        holder.productPrice.text = "$".plus(productItem["price"].toString()).plus("/")
        holder.productRating.text = productItem["reviewsValue"].toString()
        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener {
            mListener.onItemClick(holder.itemView, products[position])
            notifyDataSetChanged()
        }
    }

    inner class ViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        val productName: TextView = itemView.itemProdFeaturedName
        val productPrice: TextView = itemView.itemProdFeaturedPrice
        val productImage: ImageView = itemView.itemProdFeaturedImage
        val productWeight: TextView = itemView.txtViewWeight
        val productRating: TextView = itemView.itemProdFeaturedRate
    }

   interface OnItemClickListener {
        fun onItemClick(view: View,viewModel: Map<String, Map<String, String>>)
    }
```

My problem is How to click on product and dispaly the product detail activity.I try as the following but still not get what I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shouldn't your OnItemClickListener be like the following?

```
interface OnItemClickListener {
    fun onItemClick(view: View, product: ProductData)
}
```

And you need to change the way you start your ProductDetail activity, and put your product ID or something to identify the product selected in the extra data of the intent. For example:

```
val intent = Intent(context,ProductDetail::class.java)
intent.putExtra("PRODUCT_ID", product.id)
context.startActivity(intent)
```

Comment: Yes, It work for me, I just change "product: ProductData" By "productId: String"